# modify and append row in database and show in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

having a data in a field in mySql database such that each row may be repeated 
e.g

```
 - abc,abc,bcd,bcd,
 - abc,efg,efg,hij,
 - hij,klm,klm,klm,
```

now i don't only have to handle repetition but have show every word in dropdown list. (NOTE: abc is 1 word... bcd is also one word )

in a drop down list it will look like

```
 - abc
 - bcd
 - efg
 - hij
 - klm
```

using php 
can any one help ?

Comment: if you want to remove duplicates you can use group by in query

Comment: what you have tried? Show us your code. what is your table structure and data? there are not any guessers here.

Comment: I think the SQL `SELECT DISTINCT...` will help you.

Comment: `  $ab="SELECT DISTINCT organization FROM excel12 ORDER BY organization ASC"; `

           `$nameresult=mysql_query($ab) or die ("Query to get data from table failed: ".mysql_error());`

             `while ($namerow=mysql_fetch_array($nameresult)) {`


           ` //$nameTitle=$namerow["empid"];`
 `      $variable=$namerow["organization"];`
   `             echo "<option >`
`                   $newExpanseType`
`                </option>";`
`                echo count($variable);`
`}`

Comment: by this i'm able to get repeted data in a drop down...

Comment: DISTINCT wont help because i want every word to be displayed but it shouldn't be repeated

Comment: @barbar update your question and put your all code there + show your table structure with one row of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) as `array_unique($namerow)`